# Failing to install Alexa ASK-CLI "request deprecated"

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, alexa-skills-kit

I took a screenshot of the error message(s) I'm getting when trying to install the Alexa ask-cli.

typed in the command in terminal exactly like it says so in the [guide](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/quick-start-alexa-skills-kit-command-line-interface.html)
I also have a current version of node.js which is required.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, “request deprecated” is not the reason which causes the failure of installation. Because ask-sdk is using it so you get the warning. you can find more [Here](https://github.com/request/request-promise/issues/340#issuecomment-599240084)

The problem is, the terminal you used  did not have necessary permissions to access the /node_modules folder.

If you follow the instructions, are you sure that you ran the terminal with **Run as Administrator option** (in Windows) or **sudo** (in Unix)?
or you can try this:

> sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root

then it should work perfectly